# should I ever put a major version number into a C#/Java namespace?

Tags: c#, web-services, oop

I am designing a set of 'service' layer objects (data objects and
interface definitions) for a WCF web service (that will be consumed
by third party clients i.e. not in-house, so outside my direct control).

I know that I am
not going to get the interface definition exactly right - and am
wanting to prepare for the time when I know that I will have to
introduce a breaking set of new data objects. However, the reality
of the world I am in is that I will also need to run my first version
simultaneously for quite a while.

The first version of my service will have URL of 
http://host/app/v1service.svc

and when the times comes by new version will live at
http://host/app/v2service.svc

However, when it comes to the data objects and interfaces, I
am toying with putting the 'major' version of the interface number
into the actual namespace of the classes.

```
namespace Company.Product.V1
{
   [DataContract(Namespace = "company-product-v1")]
   public class Widget
   {
        [DataMember]
        string widgetName;
   }

   public interface IFunction
   {
       Widget GetWidgetData(int code);
   }
}
```

When the time comes for a fundamental change to the service, I will introduce
some classes like

```
namespace Company.Product.V2
{
   [DataContract(Namespace = "company-product-v2")]
   public class Widget
   {
        [DataMember]
        int widgetCode;

        [DataMember]
        int widgetExpiry;
   }

   public interface IFunction
   {
       Widget GetWidgetData(int code);
   }
}
```

The advantages as I see it are that I will be able to have a single
set of code serving both interface versions, sharing functionality
where possible. This is because I
will be able to reference both interface versions as a distinct
set of C# objects. Similarly, clients may use both interface
versions simultaneously, perhaps using V1.Widget in some legacy
code whilst new bits move on to V2.Widget.

Can anyone tell why this is a stupid idea? I have a nagging feeling
that this is a bit smelly..

notes: 
I am obviously not proposing every single new version of the service
would be in a new namespace. Presumably I will do as many
non-breaking interface changes as possible, but I know that I
will hit a point where all the data modelling will probably need a
significant rewrite.

I understand assembly versioning etc but I think this question is
tangential to that type of versioning. But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done it the way you've got (with `V1`, `V2` namespaces and a `Common` namespace) and it's worked out fairly well. Basically, I have the actual code implemented in the `Common` namespace and each of the `V1`, `V2`, etc simply act as a wrapper around it.

In our case, the older versions typically stay around for quite some time. Usually, when a client requests access to our API we'll give them the "current" version at the time and then they'll just use that forever - unless there's a serious business case for moving to a newer version, then they pretty much never do.

Answer (score 1):

Typically I have seen (and done myself) simply calling version 2 Widget2, IWidget2, etc. If you expect v2 to (probably) be the end-all, based on the lessons learned from seeing v1 in the wild, that is usually fine. But if you expect it to be more of a continually evolving thing, maybe think about a more fluid contract approach.